# basename() returning int?

Tags: c

Probably something stupid I'm missing but, why am I getting this warning?

```
static void foo(char *path) {
    char *bname;
    char *path2 = strdup(path);
    bname = basename(path2);
```

(line with basename() call): warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast

Indeed, if I change to this, the warning goes away:

```
    bname = (char *)basename(path2);
```

man 3 basename tells me:

```
char *basename(char *path);

Both dirname() and basename() return pointers to null-terminated strings.
```

What gives?

Comment: `man 3 basename` lists the header that declares basename too, FWIW.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Negative. It works properly to me. Are you sure you included the correct header?

```
#include <string.h>
#include <libgen.h>

static void foo(char *path) {
    char *bname;
    char *path2 = strdup(path);
    bname = basename(path2);
}
```

Could you tell us more about your compiling environment?

Comment: In C, if you don't have a prototype for a function (i.e. include the correct header), the compiler will assume that the function returns 'int'. It sounds like this is the OP's problem.

Comment: Roger, I believe you have the right answer.  If you posted it as an answer and not a comment, I'd select yours as the right one.  

Thanks to both of you!